# Emails, emails everywhere

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, console, email

My job entails me to send a lot of emails. I'm really bad at typing so I decided to create a program to do it for me.

I've created an email generation tool (originally posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128126/command-line-based-email-generation-tool).) I've changed everything around so that I was able to push the tool to Github, so now you can actually run it, and fall in love with it's magic and wonder. The entire run able program can be found [here](https://github.com/Ekultek/email-tool). To run this program you need to do the following:

- Download the zip (only works on Windows)
- Extract the zip file to your desktop
- Create a directory called email
- Move all the files from email-tool-4 to the email directory
- `cd` into that directory and run the program

The test module is where the issues lay, so what I'm looking for is the following:

- Is there any way to make `test runs` more object-oriented?
- How could I improve speed? This program is pretty slow (mostly because it's Ruby), but is there a way I can make it a little quicker, such as with threading?
- Can I copy to the clipboard with Ruby instead of using a third party tool?

Main source file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env ruby

# Require the files that requires all the other files and the initialize the constants

require_relative '../email/lib/lists/require/require'
require_relative '../email/lib/lists/require/constants'

# Optparse to append the flags into the OPTIONS constant

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('--tutorial', 'First time with the program..? Run this and find out how to use it') { |o| OPTIONS[:tutorial] = o }
  opts.on('--help', 'Generate the help page') { |o| OPTIONS[:help] = o }
  opts.on('-t INPUT[=INPUT]', '--type INPUT[=INPUT]', 'Specify the type of email to be generated') { |o| OPTIONS[:type] = o }
  opts.on('--example', 'Gives an example of a generic email that was created using this program') { |o| OPTIONS[:example] = o }
  opts.on('--version', 'Displays the version number of the program') { |o| OPTIONS[:version] = o }
  opts.on('--test', 'Run the test modules.') { |o| OPTIONS[:test] = o }
end.parse!

def help_page
  puts
  puts "\e[44mruby gen_email.rb -[t] <Type-of-email> --[help|tutorial|test|example|version]\e[0m"
  `notepad.exe readme.md` unless File.read('./lib/tools/read.txt').chomp == 'true'
end

# Most of these are used for information gathering and are called in other modules, such as the email templates module.
# They are just basic questions and might be moved to their own module to save lines.

def res_group
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter resolution group').split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end

def users_name
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter users full name').split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end

def cap_name(name)
  name.split.map{ |i| i.capitalize }.join(' ')
end

def summary
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter summary of issue')
end

def poc_name
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter POC name').downcase
end

def dev_domain
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter domain name')
end

def dev_server
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter server name')
end

def request_cancel
  print "\e[36mEnter ticket num to cancel:\e[0m INC00000"
  cancel = STDIN.gets.chomp
  verify_digits(cancel)
end

# Verify that the digits are correctly entered, it will not allow more then 7 digits entered at a time.

def verify_digits(int)
  begin
    if !(int[/^\d{7}$/])
      raise TicketNumError
    else
      int
    end
  rescue TicketNumError
    '<Invalid ticket number>'
  end
end

def num
  print "\e[36mEnter ticket num:\e[0m INC00000"
  num = STDIN.gets.chomp
  verify_digits(num)
end

# Verify that the timestamp is in the same format as the Remedy systems timestamp format. This will save the user
# a lot of trouble by making them input the correct timestamp before they send the email.

def verify_timestamp(stamp)
  begin
    if !(stamp[/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M\z/])
      FORMAT.warning('Invalid format of timestamp example: 06/07/2016 5:30:23 AM')
      raise TimeStampFormatError
    else
      stamp
    end
  rescue TimeStampFormatError
    timestamp
  end
end

def timestamp
  print "\e[36mEnter timestamp for removal: \e[0m"
  ts = STDIN.gets.chomp.upcase
  verify_timestamp(ts)
end

def body
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter what will happen or what you did')
end

def res
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter resolution')
end

def account
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter users account')
end

def user_id
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter username')
end

def agency
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter users agency')
end

def phone_num
  FORMAT.prompt('Enter users phone number')
end

def check_date
  SKIPDAY.date
end

def header
  CHECKTIME.check_time
end

def get_user
  user = Etc.getlogin
  @esd_user = user.split('_').first.capitalize + ' ' + user.split('_').last[0].upcase
end

def copy(email)
  clip = ClipBrd::CopyToClipboard.new
  File.open('./lib/tools/tmp/email_to_copy', 'w') { |s| s.puts(email) }
  clip.copy_to_clipbrd
  FORMAT.info('Copied to clipboard press CNTRL-V to paste')
end

def advocate_agency
  print "\e[36mEnter agency:\e[0m "
  STDIN.gets.chomp.upcase
end

# Gets the advocates and POC's from YAML files located inside of the lib/list dir. The YAML files contains every
# advocate for every agency and every POC inbox, email, and phone number.

def get_advocate
  res = advocate_agency
  file = YAML.load_file('lib/lists/advocate_list.yml')
  begin
    if file['agencies'][res] == nil
      raise InvalidPocError
    else
      file['agencies'][res]
    end
  rescue InvalidPocError
    'Invalid POC'
  end
end

def get_poc_inbox(name)

  data = [POC_INBOX['poc_inbox'][name.downcase]].flatten

  if data.count == 1
    POC_INBOX['poc_inbox'][name]
  else
    FORMAT.warning("Multiple inbox's found for #{cap_name(name)}")
    data.each.with_index(1) do |str, i|
      FORMAT.info("#{i}. #{str}")
    end
    FORMAT.warning("One of the above inbox's is the correct inbox for this ticket.")
    '<PASTE INBOX HERE>'
  end
end

def get_poc_num(name)
  data = POC_NUM['poc_phone'][name]
  begin
    if data.kind_of?(String)
      data
    else
      raise InvalidPocError
    end
  rescue InvalidPocError
    "** POC #{name} does not have a number listed **"
  end
end

def get_poc_email(name)
  data = POC_EMAIL['poc_email'][name]
  begin
    if data.kind_of?(String)
      data
    else
      raise InvalidPocError
    end
  rescue InvalidPocError
    "** POC #{name} does not have an email listed **"
  end
end

# Figure out the email type, by finding the flag argument and comparing it against a regex to validate what the user
# wants to do. For example: ruby gen_email.rb -t generic <= Will create a generic email to be sent, and copy it to the
# users clipboard.

def gather_intel
  case OPTIONS[:type]
    when /osha/
      FORMAT.info('Creating OSHA Regional email..')
      EMAILS.osha_reg
    when /pend/
      FORMAT.info('Creating 6 day hold pending email..')
      EMAILS.pend
    when /60/
      FORMAT.info('Creating 60 day hold account deletion email..')
      EMAILS.sixty_day
    when /generic/
      FORMAT.info('Creating generic email..')
      EMAILS.generic
    when /resolve/
      FORMAT.info('Creating resolution ticket..')
      EMAILS.resolve
    when /esc/
      FORMAT.info('Creating escalation ticket..')
      EMAILS.assign
    when /pii/
      FORMAT.info('Creating request to remove personal info..')
      EMAILS.remove_pii
    when /vip/
      FORMAT.info('Creating VIP user email..')
      EMAILS.vip_user
    when /inop/
      FORMAT.info('Creating INOP user email..')
      EMAILS.in_op_user
    when /dev/
      begin
        if OPTIONS[:type].to_s.include?('dev=unlock')
          message = 'unlock'
        elsif OPTIONS[:type].to_s.include?('dev=reset')
          message = 'password reset'
        else
          raise InvalidDevRequestError
        end
        FORMAT.info("Creating dev account #{message} email")
        EMAILS.dev_account(OPTIONS[:type])
      rescue InvalidDevRequestError
        FORMAT.err("#{OPTIONS[:type].to_s.split('=').last} is not a valid dev email, please try again..")
      end
    when /cancel/
      FORMAT.info('Creating cancellation request..')
      EMAILS.cancel_ticket
    else
      raise InvalidOptionError
  end
end

# Where all the big decisions are made, after the program has appended into the OPTIONS constant it will then look at
# the info called here. If nothing is given it will default to the help page method

begin
  case
    when OPTIONS[:type]
      README.check_if_read
      gather_intel
    when OPTIONS[:example]
      puts "\e[36m#{EMAILS.examples_page}\e[0m"
    when OPTIONS[:version]
      puts VERSION.version
    when OPTIONS[:test]
      TESTRUN.run_test
    when OPTIONS[:tutorial]
      TUT.flag_choices
    else
      puts help_page
  end
rescue => e
  FORMAT.err("Program failed due to #{e}")
  FORMAT.err("ERROR => #{e.backtrace.join}")
  FORMAT.info('To report this issue, fill out the text file called Issues.txt in the /lib/text_files directory.')
end
```

Comment: @DanPantry I appreciate that but I have to have that on here in order for this to be legal.

Comment: Why?  Is this required to be legal ?

Comment: No, you don't have to have that.

Comment: No, you don't. That disclaimer just adds noise. I see no reason as to why this question would be legal because you have a bold italics title case disclaimer about how the data has been anonymised. I'm not a lawyer, though, but I'm pretty sure neither are you because that disclaimer is not legally binding. It's the same as saying "This isn't mine" in a YouTube video.

Comment: @DanPantry I work for the government. They don't like things like this. I got permission to post this as long as I declared the Terms Of Service on the question.

Comment: The disclaimer is not going to make them like it more or less. What's the legality you're worried about?

Comment: @Mast I got permission to post the question as long as I declared the terms of service on it. However, since it's technically in the readme, I guess it will probably fly.

Comment: If your gov ever do try and come after this question (unlikely), the person who gave you the "permission" to post this by putting that ludicrous all-caps notice in the question will likely duck the responsibility and say "nope, wasn't me". If you have any doubts about the legality of sharing your code, don't do it, but I 100% guarantee you that your "disclaimer" won't save you any more than me saying "all rights to the copyright holder" on a music video on YT will save me. Any code posted here must be CC-by-SA by SE rules.

Comment: If you're posting this here, make sure you have a good understanding of the rights of your content.  You are not able to modify the license terms set forth by SE regardless of any type of disclaimer you add.  Make sure to have a look at the Subscriber content section here: http://stackexchange.com/legal

Answer (score 4):

#### Avoiding `raise`ing just to `rescue` immediately

```
def verify_digits(int)
  begin
    if !(int[/^\d{7}$/])
      raise TicketNumError
    else
      int
    end
  rescue TicketNumError
    '<Invalid ticket number>'
  end
end
```

You raise `TicketNumError` just to rescue it a few lines later, just avoid raising it for simplicity:

```
def verify_digits(int)
  (int[/^\d{7}$/]) ? int : '<Invalid ticket number>'
end
```

Functionality of this new un-bloated version should be identical to the original version. (I swapped the condition putting the positive first because it felt more intuitive)

#### Native methods

Using native ruby methods is a bit less concise but more readable:

```
DIGITS = "1234567890"
(int.length == 7 && int.all {|x| DIGITS.include?(x)}) ? ...
```

#### Boolean test function

In fact a better design would be an `is_valid_ticket?` function that just returns true or false because return an int if valid and an error string if invalid looks really weird / not easily re-usable:

```
def is_valid_ticket?(ticket)
  ticket.length == 7 && ticket.all {|x| DIGITS.include?(x)}
end
```

Comment: Nit: is it more idiomatic to name it "valid_ticket?"?

Comment: @gcampbell I suggest `is_valid_ticket?` using both `is` and `?`

Comment: Only issue I have with the native Ruby for the ticket numbers is that it HAS to be exactly seven digits and I'm not sure if you can trick your code or not. You'd have to fully run the program to see what I mean

Comment: @13aal Also my code checks for exactly 7 digits long

Comment: @Caridorc You have any other suggestions? I like your input thank you

Comment: @13aal I have no other suggestions, but do note that you also abised raise / rescue in other places so I would advise fixing them too in a similar manner to the example in my answer

Comment: @Caridorc hey I forgot all about this question, I'll start another bounty and award it to you, sorry

Comment: @13aal Don't worry. And remember that awarding a bounty is a sign of appreciation of extreme quality in an answer, do not feel forced to award it by any means.